# Flutter : problem with dropdown_formfield 0.1.1 plugin when put data to second menu

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I am working with flutter drop down menu. First menu is for location and second is for sublocation. It is working when clicking on first location but when changed to second and clicking on second location this error appears: 
[image]

my variable

```
//location
  String _myLocation ; 
  List data = List(); 
  //sublocation
  String _mySublocation  ; 
  List data2 = List();
```

function for location

```
 getLocation() async {
   try{
      var res = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull("http://iraqdoctors.com/api/locations"), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    setState(() {
    var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
      data = resBody;
    });
    return "Sucess";
   }catch(e){

   }
  }//get location
```

function for sublocation

```
getSublocation() async {
    try{
      var res2 = await http
        .post(Uri.encodeFull("http://iraqdoctors.com/api/getlocationflutter"),
         headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},
         body: {
            "cityname":"$_myLocation",  
          } 
         );   
    setState(() {
      var resBody2 = json.decode(res2.body);
      data2 = resBody2;
    });
    return "Sucess";
    }catch(e){

    }
  }//get sublocatio
```

Location dropdown

```
DropDownFormField(
                   hintText: 'اختر المدينة',
                    titleText: null,
                  value: _myLocation,
                  dataSource: data,                   
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _myLocation = value;                      
                      getSublocation();
                    });
                  },                  
                  textField: 'city',
                  valueField: 'city',
                ),
```

Sublocation dropdown

```
 DropDownFormField(
                  hintText: 'اختر المنطقة',
                  titleText: null,                   
                  value:  _mySublocation,                 
                  dataSource: data2,                   
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _mySublocation = value;
                     });
                  },                  
                  textField: 'state',
                  valueField: 'state',
                ),
```

Comment: Did you check if the http get at `getSubLocation()` returns a valid response? Maybe the function is entering at `catch` block and for that is no updating any value at the second dropdown

Comment: i have try remove catch but error still

Comment: No, you dont need to remove the `catch`. The problem is probably that your http call is returning an error, so the try block wont still executing (so the `setState()` wont be called) and because the http returns an error, the catch block will execute. Inside the `catch` bloc you can print something to debug if is entering to it. Whatever, the `catch` block shouldnt be empty, you may call a `setState()` inside `catch` to notify there was an error.

Comment: i put this code inside catch ..... setState(() {
       print("My error ");

      });....... but it not execute

Comment: look down screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Replace your _myLocation Dropdown with following code and it will work for you:

```
DropDownFormField(
    hintText: 'اختر المدينة',
    titleText: null,
  value: _myLocation,
  dataSource: data,                   
  onChanged: (value) async { // <-- added async.
      _myLocation = value; // <-- updated value outside of setState((){})                      
      await getSublocation();  // <-- Fetched data outside of setState((){}) 
    setState(() {  // <-- When every thing is ready setState is called
    });
  },                  
  textField: 'city',
  valueField: 'city',
),
```

I hope this helps, in case of any doubt please comment. *If this answer helps you then please accept and up-vote the answer.*

Comment: Sorry not work -_- . i think another way . problem exactly . in location menu when change and tap . work fine . but if select item and then  tap item in sublocation . and return tap another item in location menu . error accrue .

Comment: Finally . solved . just add this .... _mySublocation = " " ;  ..... to location dropdown on change

Comment: Great, I am happy that you found the solution  :)